# Fly swatter movement in Unity

Tags: c#, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game on unity (my first 2D game) and the idea of this game is to kill a fly using swatter but the problem is in the fly movement (top to down) and the collision between the swatter and the fly.

This is my code but I don't know why the collision doesn't work

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwatterController : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 1.5f;
private Vector3 target;

void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
}

void Update () {
//Movement of swatter when I click on the screen
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * 5);
} 

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    Debug.Log ("dead");
}
}
```

and I would like to know how correct my code to get right movement of the swatter( the fly swatter is placed behind the camera)
and if you have an example please post it.

**Objects used :**  Fly( circle collider 2D) , swatter(box collider 2D)

Comment: Do you have a `Rigidbody2D` component attached to either fly or swatter object? Else it won't work.

Comment: yes, on both objects with kinematic

Comment: What happens when colliding? What's the problem with fly movement?

Comment: ah, I found something, both objects are kinematic and can't be touched and when I remove kinematic they fall

Comment: Disable gravity on the rigidbodies to prevent them from falling.